# String not matched error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parsing, console

I want to parse some items from another site of mine. When I add a string

```
t.body["Some text"] = "Other text"
```

which replaces some text in body, there appears an error:

```
IndexError in sync itemsController#syncitem

string not matched
```

lib/sync_items.rb

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'uri'


module ActiveSupport
  module JSON
    def self.decode(json)
      ::JSON.parse(json)
    end
  end
end
module SyncItem
  def self.run

   uri = URI("http://example.com/api/v1/pages")
   http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
   request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
   response = http.request(request)

   parsed_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
     parsed_response.each do |item|
      t = Page.new(:title => item["title"], :body => item["body"], :format_type => item["format_type"])     
      t.body["Some text"] = "Other text"    
      t.save
   end
  end    
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`t.body` is a String object now.

To replace all occurrence of some text in string, use `gsub` or `gsub!`

```
t.body.gsub!("Some text", "Other text")
```

**Add**

To reply toro2k's comment about why such erorr, I checked and learned, using `[]` to replace something in string will ouput "Index Error" if such string doe not exist

```
s = 'foo'

s['o'] = 'a'
#=> 'fao' Works on first element

s.gsub('o', 'a')
#=> 'faa' Works on all occurence

s['b'] = 'a'
#=> IndexError: string not matched. (Non-existing string will bring such error)

s.gsub('b', 'a')
#=> nil (gsub will return nil instead of exception)
```

Comment: Why it shouldn't work? `s = 'foo'; s['oo'] = 'aa'; puts s;` prints `faa`.

Comment: @toro2k, `[]` works on first element only. s = 'foooo'; s['oo'] = 'aa'; puts s; Will output "faaoo"

Comment: `s = 'foooo'; s.gsub('oo', 'aa'); #=> 'faaaa'`

Comment: @BillyChan Of course, but I can't understand why `IndexError` in OP code is raised.